# P2P network and serialization

Tags: java, serialization, p2p

Greeting,
I am working on a program that depends on p2p local network ,i create new peers by pressing run on the IDE , i want an array list to be shared between all the threads so i can modify on it.

the problem i have faced that if the first thread write on the serialization file the newly created threads can read this modification on the list, but if the last thread modify the list the first threads can't see this modification since they desesrialize the file once on the run button press.

is there any solution for this ?(Java)

code:

```
Peer  peer = Peer.getInstance(portName, portNumber, "localhost", peers);

    new Thread(peer::startHost).start();

    peers.put(peer.getPort(), peer);

    waitASecond();
    serializePeers();
    return peer;
```

Serialize :

```
private static void serializePeers() {
        try {
          FileOutputStream fos = new 
          FileOutputStream("peersList.ser");
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
          oos.writeObject(peers);
          oos.close();

        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Desirialize:

```
private static void deserializePeers() {

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("peersList.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        peers = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, Peer>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("This is the first peer connected to the network");        }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question and be more specific.

Comment: The code is really big , what is the point you didn't get ?

Comment: Don't put the entire code base in the question, only the relevant part.

Comment: That's not enough. And edit the question and put it in the question.

Comment: code added to the question

Comment: Is there a specific exception message you're getting? Also, you should close resources in a `finally` block, not the `try`

Comment: i will refactor my code and i will use try with resources , thanks cricket_007

Comment: i have dealt with my problem , using timer on each thread and desirialize every 15 minute